Capo.js justification for order of elements in <head>
Currently, capo.js (https://rviscomi.github.io/capo.js/) suggest an optimised order of elements within the  tags at the start of an html document here https://rviscomi.github.io/capo.js/user/rules/.
capo.js are still in the process of writing their docs and there aren't currently any explanations provided for the reasoning they have used to come up with this order.
I'm struggling to understand the placement of preload hints being so low down the priority list, given that preloads are often used for site critical elements; in my current case, fonts.
Has anyone got an idea as to why capo.js have made this decision?
I've had a bit of a read as to why preloading is a good idea, and when it's appropriate to use.
